# converted my app to ARC but only 1 target shows ARC setting as YES?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I believe I successfully converted by app to ARC using the 'Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC' tool but only one of my project targets has the setting:

[image]

And if I create anything using IB it is still generating retain / release / dealloc code?

Also I now have crashes I did not before because of memory use, so I am wondering if my project is in a half converted state that is causing me random memory issues.

How do I get these other targets to use ARC  - or make sure they are using ARC?

Comment: Set the flags for these targets to `YES` and see if it causes lots of screaming from the compiler. If it doesn't, you're done :)

Comment: There is not a place for me to set the flags to YES, that option doesn't show up under the build settings for those targets

Comment: when you look at the build option for "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C", it should say "Default compiler (Apple LLVM Compiler...)" If its set to "LLVM GCC 4.2" Then "Automatic Reference Counting" won't be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually change the flags to say YES. Also want to check and make sure that none of the files have the compiler flag "-fno-objc-arc" set. (I've run into projects that were half converted this way.)

If you're still running into memory issues, run the Leaks Instrument. Even with ARC, you can still have memory leaks like [retain cycles](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html) where parent-child relationships retain each other. In such a case, you need to use weak pointers.

Comment: rookie move - I had toggle 'All' and not just 'Basic' settings for the other Targets for some reason